# Parsing CSV file in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, csv, swift2

I need to preload data into my tableView when the app launches. So i am using core data by parsing a .csv file. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/) for this purpose.
Here is my parseCSV function

```
func parseCSV (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding, error: NSErrorPointer) -> [(stationName:String, stationType:String, stationLineType: String, stationLatitude: String, stationLongitude: String)]? {
    // Load the CSV file and parse it
    let delimiter = ","
    var stations:[(stationName:String, stationType:String, stationLineType: String, stationLatitude: String, stationLongitude: String)]?

    let content = String(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding: encoding, error: error)
    stations = []
    let lines:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]

    for line in lines {
        var values:[String] = []
        if line != "" {
            // For a line with double quotes
            // we use NSScanner to perform the parsing
            if line.rangeOfString("\"") != nil {
                var textToScan:String = line
                var value:NSString?
                var textScanner:NSScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                while textScanner.string != "" {

                    if (textScanner.string as NSString).substringToIndex(1) == "\"" {
                        textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                        textScanner.scanUpToString("\"", intoString: &value)
                        textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                    } else {
                        textScanner.scanUpToString(delimiter, intoString: &value)
                    }

                    // Store the value into the values array
                    values.append(value as! String)

                    // Retrieve the unscanned remainder of the string
                    if textScanner.scanLocation < textScanner.string.characters.count {
                        textToScan = (textScanner.string as NSString).substringFromIndex(textScanner.scanLocation + 1)
                    } else {
                        textToScan = ""
                    }
                    textScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                }

                // For a line without double quotes, we can simply separate the string
                // by using the delimiter (e.g. comma)
            } else  {
                values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
            }

            // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
            let station = (stationName: values[0], stationType: values[1], stationLineType: values[2], stationLatitude: values[3], stationLongitude: values[4])
            stations?.append(station)
        }
    }


    return stations
}
```

this is my sample .csv file

```
Rithala,Underground,Yellow Line,28.7209,77.1070
```

But i am getting an error on this line

```
let station = (stationName: values[0], stationType: values[1], stationLineType: values[2], stationLatitude: values[3], stationLongitude: values[4])
            stations?.append(station)
```

**Fatal error : Array index out of range**

What am i doing wrong ? Please help me.

Comment: Put a breakpoint just before the line causing the problem, and then print `values` in the debugger using `po values`. For some reason your array doesn't have as many things in as it should do - examining what's actually there should give you an idea why

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are attempting to parse the file path rather than the contents of the file.

If you replace

```
let content = String(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding: encoding, error: error)
```

with:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL) {
  if let content = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    //existing code
  }
}
```

then the code will work for your example file.

Comment: thanx. perfect solution

Comment: Can you provide me `parseCSV ` in Swift3. Need urgently

Answer (score 26):

Here's a foolproof way of parsing a CSV file into your swift code (I'm using Swift 5 here).  I'll talk through each step for any beginners in the room.

Let's assume your CSV file looks like this:

```
Firstname,Last name,Age,Registered
Duncan,Campbell,40,True
Tobi,Dorner,36,False
Saskia,Boogarts,29,True
```

1). We need a struct (or Object) to hold each row of data.  Let's use this:

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: Int
    var isRegistered: Bool
}
```

2) We also need a variable which holds an array of each `Person`.

```
var people = [Person]()
```

3) Now - add the CSV file to your XCode project (you can drag and drop this into your project).  Make sure it has a sensible name (e.g. data.csv).

4) You now need to "locate" the data that you want to use.  Create a *filepath* which tells the code where to find your csv file:

```
guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "csv") else {
    return
}
```

5) Now we want to **read** the contents of this file.  First let's convert the whole file into one long **String**.

```
var data = ""
do {
    data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
} catch {
    print(error)
    return
}
```

6) We now have a string with *all* out data in one line.  We want to split this up into an *array of strings*, one string for each row in the data.  (BTW, the `\n` means "new line")

```
let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

7) We now have an array with 4 rows - one for the header titles, and 3 rows for each person in the data.  We're not interested in the first header row, so we can remove that one.  (Ignore this step if you don't have a header row in your data)

```
rows.removeFirst()
```

8) Now loop around each of rows.  Each row is currently a string (e.g. `Duncan,Campbell,40,True`) but we want to split it into an array of each of its 4 columns.

```
for row in rows {
    let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

9) We now have a array `columns` which has 4 strings in it.  Let's convert each column to the correct data type.

```
let firstName = columns[0]
let lastName = columns[1]
let age = Int(columns[2]) ?? 0
let isRegistered = columns[3] == "True"
```

10) And now we can create the Person object, and append it to our array.

```
let person = Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age, isRegistered: isRegistered)
people.append(person)
```

Here's the full code for anyone who is interested:

```
    struct Person {
        var firstName: String
        var lastName: String
        var age: Int
        var isRegistered: Bool
    }

    var people = [Person]()

    func convertCSVIntoArray() {

        //locate the file you want to use
        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "csv") else {
            return
        }

        //convert that file into one long string
        var data = ""
        do {
            data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        //now split that string into an array of "rows" of data.  Each row is a string.
        var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")

        //if you have a header row, remove it here
        rows.removeFirst()

        //now loop around each row, and split it into each of its columns
        for row in rows {
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")

            //check that we have enough columns
            if columns.count == 4 {
                let firstName = columns[0]
                let lastName = columns[1]
                let age = Int(columns[2]) ?? 0
                let isRegistered = columns[3] == "True"

                let person = Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age, isRegistered: isRegistered)
                people.append(person)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't handle commas between quotes e.g. : "$100,000"

Comment: thanks. But there's an error for line:


rows.removeFirst()


("Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'rows' is a 'let' constant")
you have to fix using:



        var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")



instead of



        let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error and where the error is taking place I would guess that your `values` array does not have 5 elements like you think it does. I would put a breakpoint on the line that is giving you an error and inspect your `values` variable and see how many are in it. Since your .csv file is obviously 5 elements long, then I would guess something is going wrong in your parsing.

Comment: this is what i get when i print `values`  
`[(file:///Users/sumeshagarwal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ED48342B-E512-41EB-88DD-50728C8BC9AF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1BD48658-3F83-4B41-BE83-731809E3C44B/MetroCoreData.app/stationdata.csv,  4,  0x00007fff5c189c50)]`

Comment: can u give me a link to a better tutorial to parse csv in swift ?