# how to read contents of csv stored in AWS S3 using swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to let my program to read contents of csv stored in AWS S3. I only want to read the second line in the CSV file. 
Currently I am planning to use `transferUtility.downloadDataFromBucket(bucket, key: key, expression: nil, completionHander: nil)` but I don't know how to transfer AWSTask into the entry I need.

Comment: You could try using the code in the question and accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313938/parsing-csv-file-in-swift

Comment: The problem is, I cannot get the contents of the CSV file from S3 in my program.

Comment: In other words, how can I get the contents of the files(csv, or txt) from AWS S3?